# Crate drop timings

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Are there any specific times when the plane is out for drops or the plane drop crates at random timings. I want to try a fun game where I want to only hunt and get those drops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airdrop timings are somewhat random, there is no guaranteed time to get a drop and no way to predict what time it will be before it happens.

The best way to get a game in which you get all the drops is to simply grab a bike and chase them all.

There is a slight prediction you can do, in that the first drop will always be in the play area, and each subsequent drop must fall at least within the blue circle.